# How to set variable of image src and use in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, variables, src

So if i have some codes like this

```
If(sceneA){document.getElementById("divA").src="A.png";}
 If(document.getElementById("divC")=="A.png"){document.getElementById("divB").src="B.png";}//And alot of codes here
```

How can I use a var to shorten  strings like

document.getElementById("divA").src="A.png"
document.getElementById("divB").src="B.png"

so i can use them both inside (IF) and {function}

As they have to repeat quite a few times in the codes.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Assign DOM element to variable `var divA = document.getElementById("divA")`. And then you can use `If (sceneA) { divA.src='A.png'}`.

Comment: This is good, even though i will have to set lots of divs in variables with this way . Still many many thanks, compared to whoever downvoted =)

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what functions are for.
Define a function for repeating blocks of code as follows:

```
function setSrc(divName, imgName){
    document.getElementById("div"+divName).src = imgName+".png";
}

function srcEquals(divName, imgName){
    return (document.getElementById("div"+divName).src == imgName+".png");
}
```

Then you can replace your code with this:

```
if(sceneA){setSrc("A","A");}
if(srcEquals("C", "A")){setSrc("B","B");}
```

Comment: Wow, this is smart! Does it mean i can use setsrc and srcequals both in if and function vice versa? Thank you for not downvoting and understanding my needs then submitted a good answer.  i am a very basic beginner to ever thought of this good method, thats why i asked a question. Many many thanks!

Comment: Yes you can use them anywhere. The one problem I see with your code in the question is this line: document.getElementById("divC")=="A.png". Which I think you meant to write document.getElementById("divC").src=="A.png". But it still won't work as .src will give you full path of the src image. If you hit that block, you should post another question regarding that.